# What are the requirements/impact of alerting a user when they're near a location?

Tags: android, iphone

For an Android/iPhone app, if I want the app to notify someone when they get near certain locations, what are the requirements/impact of:

1. Does the require the app to be open (like the Tesla app needs to be running to unlock the car doors)? Or is there a background mode where it can be woken up when it gets near the specified locations?
2. Does it burn up additional power to constantly check the location to see if it's near any specified location? (I'm assuming this is a no as the phones are constantly reporting their speed in traffic.)